# methode getconnection not found in \Doctrine\Common\Persistence

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I am following a tutoral on Symfony 4 where we want to create a raw query. Here is the code that is provided in the tutorial :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
    $sql = '
    SELECT * FROM user u
    WHERE u.id > :id
    ';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['id' => 3]);

   //more code 
    }
```

But when I try to do the same the methode getconnection seem to not be recognized by my IDE and it gives me this message :

> methode getconnection not found in \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager

Any ideas about what shoould I do ? I will apreciate it.

Comment: Your code should work in spite of the IDE complaining.  getManager is type hinted to return an ObjectManager interface but, assuming you are using a database, actually returns an EntityManagerInterface which is derived from ObjectManager.  It is the EntityManagerInterface that contains the getConnection method.  Probably the best thing to do is to inject the EntityManagerInterface directly into your method as shown in the comment here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database

Comment: You might be better off just forgetting about the tutorial and following the official Symfony docs on how to use the dbal connection object: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html

Comment: Thank you very much Sir ! As you said it's just a problem in the IDE . it worked after all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it's not really an error, but more of a static analysis result, you can try to quiet the static analysis tool used (not exactly sure, which one it is) you could do this when getting your entity manager:

```
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface $entityManager */
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

if the static analysis tool is any good, it will accept the comment/hint and recognize the entity manager for what it truly is and probably will stop complaining.

(the question I ask myself: is there a reason you use plain SQL instead of ... you know ... the entity manager, like ... `$user = $entityManager->find(User::class, 3);` ... unless your User is not an entity for whatever reason)

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help ! my IDE recognized getConnection , but after that he didnt recognize my sqsl syntaxe. But it's okay it works in both cases !thank you very much Sir . And for why I am using sql syntax it's just a tutorial where they show you all the possible cases , but your way of thinking is very reasonable and I will use it as an advice if I want to develop my proper application in the futur . Thank you again!